# UV Warp moving entire texture on character

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

So I am trying to use a UV warp to animate 2D eyes on my character mesh from this tutorial here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY

[image: Character]

Once I start moving the bone the eyes are working fine, but it also move the entire texture for the character model. For example: [image: Texture Issue]

I know this has something to do with the UVs but I'm having trouble finding a solution. Please let me know if there's any more information I can provide. Thank you.

UPDATE: So I believe that I found what's causing the issue. The bone is somehow selecting all the UVs rather than just the eye UV box I made.[image]

Is it possible to separate that particular UV from all the other ones? That way I believe I can get the eyes to move the way it is supposed to.

Comment: Did you assign the different material for the eye, as you can see at 6:50 in the video?

Comment: Yes, both textures are in there own material slots.